# How can I get html.textbox value to render page param?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, html.textboxfor

Using .net mvc5 ef6.

This is my a part of index.cshtml view.

```
@Html.TextBox(name:"bookId")
@RenderPage("~/Views/Home/PopUp.cshtml", renderpageparam )
```

Comment: You need some basics of ASP.NET MVC... you are thinking in WebForms. The TextBox will be empty at the moment you render the View. So, in order to post the user entered text, you need to think of forms o javascript.

Comment: @Romias thank u. but how can i write a js code for this? how can i get value from textbox via using js? whats the js codes for this?